# ssh key not working as file variable in GitLab

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

Why is this file variable not working? I configured `id_rsa` as protected file variable under CI/CD variables. Here is my GitLab pipeline:

```
my_job:
  script:
  - ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i $id_rsa my_host
```

What else is needed here?

I am getting this error:

```
Warning: Identity file -----BEGIN not accessible: No such file or directory.
ssh: Could not resolve hostname openssh: Name or service not known
```

Thank you

I tried to run this command with having `id_rsa` file in my file repository and it was working fine. Only when I hide the keys file to file variables it stops working.

Comment: There's probably an error in your variable definition or something overwriting it, as its showing a content instead of a temp file path in your error message. I'd recommend renaming it to something else than id_rsa to ensure that.

Answer (score 0):

`-i $id_rsa` is supposed to be the *path* to a private key, not the actual private key *content* itself.

In your case, `$id_rsa` represents the private key content.

Follow instead "[Using SSH keys with GitLab CI/CD](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ssh_keys)" and see if you can add your key to an ssh-agent, instead of using `-i`.

Answer (score 0):

Good job guys. Adding double quotes helped here - "$id_rsa". Plus, before running ssh I changed the file mode as well. Final solution is:

my_job:
script:

- chmod 700 "$id_rsa"
- ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i "$id_rsa" my_host

Comment: Assuming that `$id_rsa` contains a file *path*, instead of the actual private key content, as it was the case in your question, then yes, that would work

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change your private key
Use ssh-keygen -t ed25519 when generating the key. Looks like Gitlab does not support the default RSA keys.

```
ssh-keygen -t ed25519
```

Answer (score -1):

> Warning: Identity file -----BEGIN not accessible: No such file or directory.

indicates that `ssh` received a wrong Identity file.

Seems "-----BEGIN  ..." is set to $id_rsa. Maybe bash syntax error exists in you scripts.

Put `echo "$id_rsa"` above `ssh` command to check $id_rsa is right or not.